# Recursive formula for $\int_0^1 x^n (x + a)^{-1} \,dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm stuck on a textbook exercise that asks me to define the integral $I_n$ in the title in terms of $I_{n-1}$. The only technique I'm aware of for determining integral recurrence relations is integration by parts and that does not seem to work out here no matter how I pick $u$ and $v$. Is there another technique I need to apply or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(x + a)}dx=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\frac{x}{(x + a)}dx=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{a}{(x + a)}\right)dx$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, splitting up the fraction never crossed my mind. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**
Write $x^n$ as $x^{n-1}\cdot (x+a-a)$